# Не могу вывести свойство инфоблока в битрикс 1с

Tags: php, битрикс

Не получается вывести свойство инфоблока в битрикс 1с.Я написал следующий код, но не получается получить свойства элемента. Выходит поле NAME, но свойство не выходит.Буду рад любой помощи.

```
<?
   if(CModule::IncludeModule("iblock"))
   { 

$arSelect = Array("18", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM","CURRENCY_COURSE");
$arFilter = Array("ID"=>IntVal(191), "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>50), $arSelect);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
 $arFields = $ob->GetFields();

}
   }
```

Comment: "В списке полей элемента можно сразу выводить значения его свойств. Обязательно должно быть использованы поля IBLOCK_ID и ID, иначе не будет работать корректно. Кроме того, также  в качестве одного из полей необходимо указать PROPERTY_<PROPERTY_CODE>, где PROPERTY_CODE - ID или символьный код (задается в верхнем регистре, даже если в определении свойств инфоблока он указан в нижнем регистре)." https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php 
Если вам нужно свойсво CURRENCY_COURSE, то его в $arSelect нужно указывать как PROPERTY_CURRENCY_COURSE.